# How to resort data to go into descending order from a text file

Tags: python

I am writing a nutrition program and the data from a persons meals are read into the program and then the user can add a new meal to the Text File:
[image: Text File]

but after they add a new piece of data I don't know how to make it where the time of that meal can be rearranged by descending order. The text file contains a meals time, the meal, the food within the meal and some extra information about the food. I haven't tried anything as I am new to Python and I am stuck with this. The code should make sure that any new data that is added will be set in place by the Time row (goes from earliest time to latest)

This is the code for where a new meal can be added:

```
 elif introduction == '5':
    def main():
        another = 'y'
       
        food_file = open("food.txt", 'a')

        
        while another == 'y' or another == 'Y':
                
            print('Enter the food data:')
            time = float(input('Enter the time you had this meal (in four digits):'))
            descr = input('Description(Snack etc.): ')
            meal = str(input('What was the meal?: '))
            serving = int(input('Please enter the serving: '))
            kcal = int(input('Please enter the calories: '))
            sfatg = float(input('Please enter the saturated fat: '))
            
            
            food_file.write(str(time) + ' , ' + str(descr) + ' , ' +  str(meal) + ' , ' + str(serving) + ' , ' + str(kcal))

            print('Do you want to add another record?')
            another = input('Y = yes, anything else = no: ')

            
            food_file.close()
            print('Data appended to food.txt.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CSV fiel format instead, as you're using `','` to separate your values, and you can also open it in Excel and it will appear as a table with columns.

```
# myFile.csv

time,desc,meal,serving,kcal,sfatg
10:00,meal,hamburger,1,1500,1000
12:00,snack,apple,1,100,0
08:00,meal,pizza slice,2,500,10
```

As you can see, the table is not sorted by time. We can use a cool python package called `pandas` to import our csv as a table and sort the table.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("myFile.csv")
df = df.sort_values(by=['time'])
print(df)
```

And the output will be:

```
    time   desc         meal  serving  kcal  sfatg
2  08:00   meal  pizza slice        2   500     10
0  10:00   meal    hamburger        1  1500   1000
1  12:00  snack        apple        1   100      0
```

And if we want to reverse the order?

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['time'], ascending=False)
```

and we get:

```
    time   desc         meal  serving  kcal  sfatg
1  12:00  snack        apple        1   100      0
0  10:00   meal    hamburger        1  1500   1000
2  08:00   meal  pizza slice        2   500     10
```

Now to add a row?

```
df = df.append(
    {
        "time": "05:00",
        "desc": "drink",
        "meal": "beer",
        "serving": 10,
        "kcal": 1000,
        "sfatg": 10,
    },
ignore_index = True)
```

and we get

```
    time   desc         meal  serving  kcal  sfatg
1  12:00  snack        apple        1   100      0
0  10:00   meal    hamburger        1  1500   1000
2  08:00   meal  pizza slice        2   500     10
3  05:00  drink         beer       10  1000     10
```

Make sure to move the sorting function after you append something, otherwise it will just get tacked on the end out of order.

Now let's save our file

```
df.to_csv("myNewFile.csv")
```

Easy!, when you open it you'll notice a column with a count of the rows, we can remove that before hand

```
df.to_csv("myNewFile.csv", index=False)
```

Here is all the code

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in the file
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

# Add a new row
df = df.append(
    {
        "time": "05:00",
        "desc": "drink",
        "meal": "beer",
        "serving": 10,
        "kcal": 1000,
        "sfatg": 10,
    },
ignore_index = True)

# Sort the table
df = df.sort_values(by=['time'], ascending=False)

# Print the table
print(df)

# Save to a file
df.to_csv("myNewFile.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is the *simplest* solution given your code, but Amadan's answer is much more informative.

```
with open("food.txt", "r") as food_file:
    # read the lines from the file
    results = [line.strip() for line in food_file.readlines()]

with open("food.txt", "w") as food_file:
    # write back the sorted lines
    for line in sorted(results):
        food_file.write(result_line)
        food_file.write("\n")
```

Please note that since your "timestamps" are only four digits (i'm assuming you mean hours, minutes?) your code doesn't care whether a user eats something on different days.

In general, try to use with `with open ...` rather than manually calling `open()` and `close()` on a file (consider if the user presses ctrl-c before typing 'y' at your `another` prompt, the file handle will be left open)

One simple optimization you could do is to consider concatenating the user's input to the `results` array after reading the file, then write the sorted results plus their new input back into the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could go about this.

- You could read the whole file into a list, add the new row, sort the list, then write out the file. Note that this sort of thing is vastly helped by the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Note that writing to the same file is unsafe; if it gets interrupted, you end up with data loss. Thus, writing to a temporary file and then atomically replacing the original with the temporary file is the standard practice.
- You could append a line to the file, then invoke the UNIX [`sort` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html). You can use [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), or if you need more control, the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to achieve this. Same considerations about data corruption apply.
- You could use an actual database, which will make it very easy to get sorted data at any time. In particular, if you don't need to worry about simultaneous access by many users and if the size of your database is reasonable, you can use the [`sqlite3` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). For this, you would need to learn some SQL though; at minimum, [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), [`INSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) and [`UPDATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statements.

The first approach is the only one using pure Python, so here goes:

```
import csv
import os
import tempfile

def add_row(file_name, new_row):
    read_handle = open(file_name, mode='rt')
    write_handle = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
            mode='wt', delete=False, dir=os.path.dirname(file_name))
    with read_handle, write_handle:
        rows = list(csv.reader(read_handle))
        rows.append(new_row)
        csv.writer(write_handle).writerows(sorted(rows))
    os.rename(write_handle.name, file_name)

add_row("foo.csv", ["1503", "Snack", "Duck", "1", "Lots", "Dunno"])
add_row("foo.csv", ["1543", "Mouthwash", "Mouthwash", "1", "Zero", "Zero"])
add_row("foo.csv", ["1201", "Lunch", "Doughnuts", "12", "Don't ask", "Oh my god"])
```

will result in three rows being added to `foo.csv`, in order (`1201`, then `1503`, then `1543`). I haven't put in any logic for *creating* the file, so make sure one exists beforehand.